# can create custom json string with instantiated data class in java

Tags: java, json

There is a class defined follows:

```
@Data // lombok
public class MyData {
    @Required // my custom annotation
    String testValue1;
    Integer testValue2;
}
```

And myData is instantiated like that:

```
MyData myData = new MyData();
myData.setTestValue1("test1");
myData.setTestValue2(123);
```

I want to serialize myData as json string as follows:

```
{
    "testValue1": {
        "type": "String",
        "isRequired": "true",
        "value": "test1"
    },
    "testValue2": {
        "type": "Integer",
        "isRequired": "false",
        "value": "123"
    },
}
```

Is there a good way to create json string?

edit|

I put quotes on json string that to be able to valid.

I want to set key as field name and create additional field information.
set field type on "type" key and
if field has @Required annotation, set true on "isRequired" and
set instantiated field value on "value".

Comment: That's not valid JSON. I assume you mean to use quote for `type` and `value`?

Comment: @shmosel Yes youre right. I edit my question

Comment: I don't know if you'll find any out-of-the-box solution for such a specific use case, but it's pretty straightforward to read the field type and annotations with reflection and compose the JSON yourself.

Comment: @shmosel I will try it with your opinion. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I played a bit around with Jackson Serialization and came to this result (certainly unfinished and not fully tested, but works with your given object).:

Module to make Spring / Jackson known of the new Serializer.

```
@JsonComponent
public class TestSerializerModule extends SimpleModule {

    @Override
    public String getModuleName() {
        return TestSerializerModule.class.getSimpleName();
    }

    @Override
    public Version version() {
        return new Version(
                1,
                0,
                0,
                "",
                TestSerializerModule.class.getPackage().getName(),
                "TestModule"
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
        context.addBeanSerializerModifier(new BeanSerializerModifier() {

            @Override
            public JsonSerializer<?> modifySerializer(SerializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonSerializer<?> serializer) {

                if (beanDesc.getBeanClass().equals(MyData.class)) { //Add some smart logic here to identify your objects
                    return new TestSerializer();
                }

                return serializer;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then the Serialisier itself:

```
public class TestSerializer extends StdSerializer<Object> {

    protected TestSerializer() {
        super(Object.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        ClassIntrospector classIntrospector = provider.getConfig().getClassIntrospector();
        BasicBeanDescription beanDescription = (BasicBeanDescription) classIntrospector.forSerialization(provider.getConfig(), provider.constructType(value.getClass()), null);


        // Start of the MyValue Object
        gen.writeStartObject();
        beanDescription.findProperties().forEach(p -> {

                    // Requiered if Annoation is present
                    boolean required = p.getField().hasAnnotation(Required.class);

                    try {

                        // Write all the wanted fields
                        gen.writeFieldName(p.getName());
                        gen.writeStartObject();
                        gen.writeBooleanField("isRequired", required);
                        gen.writeStringField("type", p.getField().getRawType().getSimpleName());
                        gen.writeFieldName("value");

                        Object value1 = p.getGetter().getValue(value);
                        
                        // Use existing serializer for the value    provider.findValueSerializer(value1.getClass()).serialize(value1, gen, provider);
                        gen.writeEndObject();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }

        );
        gen.writeEndObject();


    }
}
```

Running this test :

```
@JsonTest
class TestSerializerTest {


    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Test
    public void testSerializer() throws Exception {


        MyData value = new MyData();
        value.setTestValue1("test1");
        value.setTestValue2(123);

        String s = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(value);

        System.out.println(s);

    }


}
```

gives me this output:

```
{"testValue1":{"isRequired":false,"type":"String","value":"test1"},"testValue2":{"isRequired":false,"type":"Integer","value":123}}
```

Hope that gives you an idea where to start and how to proceed from here!

Comment: thanks for your answer. I couldn't solve about setup moduling error yet but I think this answer will be solve my problem enoughly.
Let me ask you one more favor, could you provide reference documents url about this for me?

Comment: Some simple information about custom serializing with Jackson can be found here: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization